# The equation $f(x)=f(a^n)^k$ always has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials

Fix two positive integers $a,k\ge2$, and let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial. Suppose that for all sufficiently large positive integers $n$, there exists a rational number $x$ satisfying $f(x)=f(a^n)^k$. Does there exists a polynomial $g\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f(g(x))=f(x)^k$ for all real $x$?
Is this conjecture true? A proof would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This is a (pretty hard) math olympiad problem. You can find a solution here http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2728418&sid=4c15bfa18dbd27781fe66e0649391f49#p2728418.

Comment: If it is an olympiad problem, it shouldn't be on MO.

Comment: The question was copied verbatim from the website Rodgrigo pointed to.  It seems strange that the OP did not mention the question's source, or that a solution was given at that source.

Comment: Looks like I was caught. I actually wanted a solution of that problem. So I posted it here. A lot of my problems in Math SE were ignored, but none at MO. So I posted it here. But if I mentioned that it was from an olympiad it would migrate to Math SE and again be ignored. Sorry for not mentioning the source. I accept all punishment for that. :(